# New dependency causing errors on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently getting the following error after I added a new dependency when I run `npm run build`.

How can I get my project to ignore this error?

```
myProject@2.71.0 declaration /Users/name/projects/my-project/packages/pack/componentName
node ../../../build-scripts/typescript/declaration.js

Bundling declaration file...
node_modules/react-responsive/types/index.d.ts(6,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/react-responsive/types/index.d.ts(6,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/react-responsive/types/index.d.ts(6,118): error TS1005: ';' expected.

lerna ERR! npm run declaration stderr:
child_process.js:866
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: tsc -p tsconfig.json --declarationDir './lib' --emitDeclarationOnly
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:790:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:863:15)
    at exec (/Users/name/projects/my-project/packages/pack/componentName/build-scripts/exec.js:4:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/my-project/packages/pack/componentName/build-scripts/typescript/declaration.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
}
npm ERR! componentName@2.71.0 declaration: `node ../../../build-scripts/typescript/declaration.js`
npm ERR! Failed at the componentName@2.71.0 declaration script.
```

I tried adding the annotation `// @ts-nocheck` on top of the component file which makes no diff.

I am using typescript version `3.7.3` and can't change this version.

I am currently already ignoring `node_modules`. No other component has this issue less this component with it's new dependency.

This is a React based typescript project which is essentially a library.

So at the top level there is a tsconfig.json as follows.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "diagnostics": false
  },
  "types": ["jest"],
  "include": ["packages/**/*", "global.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.schema.ts",
    "**/*.schema.tsx",
    "**/_*/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Following that, each component is within its own folder in following structure.

```
componentName
-- src
---- index.tsx
-- package.json
-- tsconfig.json
```

The component where I added this new dependency, the package.json looks as follows.

```
{
    "name": "component-name",
    "version": "2.71.0",
    "main": "./lib/index.js",
    "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "clear": "node ../../../build-scripts/clear.js",
        "build": "node ../../../build-scripts/babel/build.js",
        "declaration": "node ../../../build-scripts/typescript/declaration.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "lib"
    ],
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-responsive": "^9.0.2", // new dependency 
    }
}
```

This is the tsconfig.json for this component.

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src", "../../../global.d.ts"]
}
```

This is the declaration.js file.

```
const exec = require("../exec");

console.log("Bundling declaration file...");
exec(
  `tsc -p tsconfig.json --declarationDir './lib' --emitDeclarationOnly`
);
```